# Storage a single long character string with minimum disk usage with R

Tags: r, linux, string, character, storage

I want to use R to storage a DNA sequence with minimum disk usage. A DNA sequence is a very long (typically tens of million characters) character string composed of "A", "C", "G" and "T".

Suppose "abc.fa" is a text file on the disk contains 43 million characters, I have tried the following different approaches.

(1) Without using R, I use the `gzip` command of Linux to compress the file "abc.fa" and the result file "abc.fa.gz" occupied about 13 Mb of the disk space.

(2) Using the `Biostring` package of R.

```
dat <- readDNAStringSet("abc.fa")
writeXStringSet(dat, file="abc.comp.fa", compress=TRUE)
```

The output file `abc.comp.fa` also occupied about 13 Mb of the disk space.

(3) Using the `save` function of R to storage the sequence as a `character` string of R.

```
dat <- readDNAStringSet("abc.fa")
dat <- as.character(dat)
save(dat, file="abc.chara.fa", compress="xz")
```

The output file `abc.chara.fa` occupied about 9 Mb of the disk space.

I am wondering if there are more efficient approaches to storage this kind of sequences with even smaller disk usage in R.

Thanks.

Comment: What about an (ad hoc) database?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I made some research. Both `save` and `saveRDS` comes with three different possible compression algorithms, as you already know. What could me more interesting for you is the `compression_level` argument, that comes with `save`. It is an integer from 1 to 9, by default set to 6 for gzip compression and to 9 for bzip2 or xz compression. `saveRDS` comes only with the default values for the three compression algorithms.

The higher compression rate has drawbacks in read and write times. I previously suggested `saveRDS` since you need to save a single object. In any case, if you are not interested in responsiveness (since the data object is quite small), I suggest you to test the three algorithms with `compression_level = 9` and verify which one fit better your needs.

EDIT 2:

As far as I know, the structure of the string should not affect the size of the object, but I have an hypothesis. Your data has only four values, namely A, C, T, G. Data are often stored and represented in the standard IEEE 754 format. It allows a far wider range of representations. Actually, you should be ok with a two digits representation system, where 00, 01, 10, 11 are capable of deal with your data, saving otherwise unused space. You should check how your data is represented, and eventually consider for a conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However `saveRDS` occupied even more disk space than `save`.

Comment: @VenYao, I focused the answer on something more useful, perhaps. I hope this helps.

Comment: I tested. `compress="xz"` is the most efficient approach. I am wondering if we can change the structure of this single long character string so that we can save it with minimum disk space usage.